# How to play audio for browse files in html5 using typescript?

Tags: angular, html, typescript

```
<input type="file" id="soundUrl" (change)="onAudioPlay()" />
<audio id="sound" controls></audio>
```

above is my HTML code and i need to play audio after selecting mp3 file using typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `audio` element with a source using either the [`src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Attributes) attribute, or `source` element(s) nested inside the audio tag - useful for multiple sources.

In your case you could probably bind a property on your component to the source tag and update it using your `onAudioPlay()` method - assuming you're inputting a source path via the input tag.

[Here is a link to a basic example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Examples)